# How to set default page in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have set routes in `routes.php` for my default page but it shows a 404 error when opening `localhost/mywebsite`

```
$route['default_controller'] = "page";
$route['404_override'] = 'page';
```

I have set the above code in `routes.php` which gives a 404 error. The page controller has been created.

Comment: make sure the **index** function are contain in the Page controller

Comment: can you add here your controller code.

Comment: try this, localhost/mywebsite/index.php - Make sure you replace this later in your config file (index_page)

Comment: change this:`$route['404_override'] = 'page';` to this:`$route['404_override'] = '';`

Comment: public function index() {
     // Fetch the page template
     $this->data['page'] = $this->page_m->get_by(array('slug' => (string) $this->uri->segment(1)), TRUE);
     count($this->data['page']) || show_404(current_url());
index function

Comment: codeGodie i tried it already but didn't worked

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure following things:

1. Webserver rewrite module is installed
2. htaccess file is properly configured
3. index function is present in page controller

Answer (score 0):

You configured default controller & 404_override URL with the same value.

When ever you access to your web site automatically open page controller index function

ie `ur_project_url/page/index`

OR

`ur_project_url/index.php/page/index`

when ever you can get the 404 error also open same page controller index function

ie ur_project_url/page/index

OR

ur_project_url/index.php/page/index

please check your controllers and function and routes ,`htacess` file

please remove your url `index.php` using `htacess`

in config folder `$config['log_threshold'] = 0;`  to `$config['log_threshold'] = 1;` check log files

Comment: i have removed the index.php file from url below is the index function     public function index() {
     // Fetch the page template
     $this->data['page'] = $this->page_m->get_by(array('slug' => (string) $this->uri->segment(1)), TRUE);
     count($this->data['page']) || show_404(current_url());